# Phrase for daily life

Tags: phrase-requests

I was wondering if there is a phrase for everyday (daily) life in literature?

I am from Germany and the only one I know is "Slice of life" but I'm not sure if it's common.

Why I need to know: I'm reading a novel *Why we broke up* and it's about nothing extraordinary but just a relationship between a boy and a girl - and I described it as "everyday-lifestyle" - but when I showed it to an English native speaker, he didn't know what I meant.

Comment: I don't know about literature, but the long-running UK radio soap-opera, [*The Archers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Archers), is tagged "an everyday story of country folk."

Comment: Hey thanks for your fast reply! I'm not quite sure if this applies to literature since I'm looking for a generic description

Comment: You could say your book deals with [the mundanities of life](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+mundanities+of+life%22), or depicts [a mundane existence](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+mundane+existence%22).

Comment: Wow well that's really a good phrase! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: 'everyday life' is how one normally says it. 'everyday lifestyle' probably threw them; 'lifestyle' is the particular way one leads ones entire life, both everyday and in special circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

That novel is a *contemporary (young adult) realistic fiction  romance*. (It's "one of the most talked-about romances in teen literature"–Kirkus Reviews).

[Little, Brown](http://littlebrownlibrary.com/why-we-broke-up/), the publisher of *Why We Broke Up* classifies it as **Realistic Fiction**. This genre does not include fantasy, so Harry Potter, vampires and zombies are not included within it.

[Good Books](https://www.goodreads.com/shelf/show/realistic-fiction-romance) lists many *young adult realistic fiction  romances*.

Study.com defines *Realistic fiction*:

> Realistic fiction is a genre consisting of stories that could have actually occurred to people or animals in a believable setting. These stories resemble real life, and fictional characters within these stories react similarly to real people. Stories that are classified as realistic fiction have plots that highlight social or personal events or issues that mirror contemporary life, such as falling in love, marriage, finding a job, divorce, alcoholism, etc. They depict our world and our society.

Characteristics of realistic fiction include

> 1. Realistic fiction stories tend to take place in the present or recent past.
> 2. Characters are involved in events that could happen.
> 3. Characters live in places that could be or are real.
> 4. The characters seem like real people with real issues solved in a realistic way (so say goodbye to stories containing vampires, werewolves, sorcerers, dragons, zombies, etc.).
> 5. The events portrayed in realistic fiction conjure questions that a reader could face in everyday life.

Comment: +1 I think my daughter is reading this, but hard to tell as the names are different in Spanish and German. I am not sure if I want my daughter reading something that does not have zombies, vampires, werewolves, or magic in it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[Daily grind](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/daily_grind) - A daily routine of work or activity, especially as considered to be dull or tiresomely repetitious; the usual day's work or routine, regarded as unremitting and laborious.

Shakesphere's

> We are but warriors for the working day

*Henry V, Act 4, Scene 3*, comes to mind. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider *(daily/everyday) **humdrum/routine***.

ODO:

> **[humdrum](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/humdrum)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> [mass noun] Monotonous routine:
>   ‘an escape from the humdrum of his
>   life’
>
> ‘Just watching them and thinking that there had to be something more
>   in this life for all of us than the ***everyday humdrum***.’
>
> **[routine](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/routine)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A sequence of actions regularly followed:
>   ‘I settled down into a routine of work and sleep’
>
> ‘Almost as routine as brushing one's teeth, checking e-mail has worked
>   its way into the ***daily routine*** of millions.’

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like typical *boy meets girl*.

> a typical romantic situation or story about two people falling in love
>
> > All the plots of this week’s new movies are *boy meets girl*.

-- [MacMillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/boy-meets-girl)

Answer (score 0):

The fancy word is ***quotidian***.  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quotidian)

> Ordinary or everyday; mundane:
>
> Example: his story is an achingly human one, mired in quotidian 
>   details

From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=q&p=5&allowed_in_frame=0)

> (mid-14c., "everyday, daily," from Old French cotidian (Modern French
>   quotidien), from Latin quotidianus "daily," from Latin quotus "how
>   many? which in order or number?" (see quote (v.)) + dies "day" (see
>   diurnal). Meaning "ordinary, commonplace, trivial" is from mid-15c)

The OP's phrase *everyday-lifestyle* is fine.  I am surprised that the person he/she was speaking to did not understand it! That person certainly would not understand *quotidian*, but the OP's English teacher will.

There is also a medical usage, which the OP should be aware of [The Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/156917?redirectedFrom=quotidian#eid):

> Recurring or occurring every day, spec. at twenty-four-hour intervals;
>   (of a disease, esp. malaria) characterized by paroxysms recurring at
>   this interval.